# How to use threading with django and gunicorn

Tags: django, multithreading, gunicorn

I am trying to use the threading library inside of a django application that uses gunicorn. When I run my code locally everything is good, but as soon as I try to call the view from production I get a context error. I believe this is due to gunicorn.

Here is the error

```
RuntimeError: cannot exit context: thread state references a different context object
```

Here is my code.

```
t = threading.Thread(
target=myFunction, args=[arg1]
            )
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution I found as I could not find any reference to this exact issue and resolution. It turns out the issue was not with python or django but rather Gunicorn itself. In order to use threading I had to add the --threads param to the service file.

```
/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --name=my_app --pythonpath=/home/django/myenv --bind unix:/home/django/myenv/my_app/gunicorn.socket  my_app.wsgi:application --workers=4 --threads=2 --worker-class=gthread
```

I also set the worker class to gthread